# copying files without rewriting

Tags: command-line, rsync, filemanager

I am using two HDDs in my small server and I copied HDD1 to HDD2 using `dd`. HDD2 is my backup and I want to keep it up-to-date, but I don't want to `dd` every time. I'd like to regularly copy all new files to HDD2, without rewriting everything (because it takes a really long time). All files = config files, data etc.

How can i do it? I tried

```
rsync -avxHAX --numeric-ids --progress / /media/ken/asdasdx --exclude={/dev/*,/mnt/*,/media/*} > ~/rsync.out
```

But that seems to rewrite all the files as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across the answer...

```
man rsync
--ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
```